# is vala dead? because it's a nice language

Tags: development

i've been following ubuntu since 9.04

installing it and trying it - then found gnome

now that gnome is going to be standard desktop come next release - i thought i would like to be involved in helping maintain and improve the platform

so - i try to find an OO language for Gnome and up pops Vala

start teaching myself and then read the forums that Vala is dead

I like it it - it's an elegant language (even if it does generate C - which is a good thing)

i used to work for unisys and the "language" now known as Jade used to be a linc program generating cobol code

i'd like to help

Comment: oh btw - i'm actually running elementary to ask this - i respect the effort

Comment: don't really know about Vala being dead ... but on the web their site "June 26, 2017: Vala 0.36.4 released" so development still seems active ... I guess it depends upon why you are learning the language ...

Answer (score 5):

Nope. :)

Vala is being maintained, and elementary plans to continue to use it (and contribute back when needed!) for the foreseeable future. As Michael Cotanzaro [has written](https://blogs.gnome.org/mcatanzaro/2017/02/19/on-problems-with-vala/), Vala is still the best choice for GNOME and GTK+ development. It's a purpose-built language for GTK+, after all, which means its bindings and integration are second-to-none.

In the future if a language like Rust or Go exceeds the tight integrations into the GNOME stack with bindings and lots of example code, then maybe those languages would make more sense. But right now Vala is in an excellent position and the rumors of its death (mostly from a single developer's personal blog post) are greatly exaggerated.